# search string in text file and capture following n characters

Tags: python, curl

I'm using `subprocess.Popen` and `stdout` to write the output of a `curl` from Backendless (BaaS).

What's written to the output file is a long single line of data, separated by commas. Here's a small portion of it.

```
{"APIEndpoint":"asdfaasdfa","created":1429550024000,"updated":null,"objectId":"EE51537D-A9AC-721C-FF33-F4B258931E00"...}
```

The value I need from this output file is the 37-character string following "objectID":". I've read many similar questions but haven't been able to find a solution to this specific one. I've tried something like:

```
objectid = 37
searchfile open('backendless.txt', 'r')
for line in searchfile:
    if "\"objectId\":\"" in line:
        print(right[:objectidd])
```

which returns nothing. Please correct me if I'm using `line` incorrectly. I'm very new to this. Also, is there a way to achieve the same result without saving it to the text file first and instead performing the `curl` with `PIPE` and `communicate`?

I'm using Python 3.4. Thank you.

**EDIT/SOLUTION:**

```
from subprocess import *
baascurl = Popen(['curl', '-H', appid, '-H', secretkey, '-H', apptype, '-H', contenttype, '-X', 'GET', '-v', 'https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Latency/last'], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
objidbytes = baascurl.decode(encoding='utf-8')
objid = json.loads(objidbytes)["objectId"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data looks pretty much like JSON, so maybe you can use Python's [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module:

```
import json
objid = json.loads(datastring)["objectId"]
```

If you want to stay on the text level, the right tool for this job are regular expressions. Look into Python's [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module.

```
import re
m = re.search(r'"objectId":"([^"]+)"', datastring, re.IGNORECASE)
if m:
    objid = m.group(1)
```

Comment: You were absolutely right, the data is JSON. I was getting `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'` but after searching, I discovered how to convert the output to a string. Everything works perfectly. @ChristianAichinger Thank you so much for your help. I will add the final code to my original question for future reference.